# How to use different button to access same class?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-camera

I have three activity.

`A`>>`B`>>`C`

`C`>>return image and value to `B`>>return to `A`>>If textView not null can intent to `B`

`C` has a camera function which will return the `image` from `B` to `A`.

In `A`, it has one `editText` and a `button`. If `editText` not `null`, it can be clicked and intent to `B` by passing the `value` and `image` for edit. But the problem now is, when I click the button, I will see the image display on the `image view` even it is not get the image from c!

I know I can use `view.setImageDrawable(null)` to clear the image but it cannot work in my case since I access the `B` two times with different widget!

**Activity C**

```
  ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)  //return to B
            {
                Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
                text=t.getText().toString();
                b.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                b.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                b.layout(0, 0, b.getMeasuredWidth(), b.getMeasuredHeight());
                b.buildDrawingCache(true);
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                if (b.getDrawingCache() != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getDrawingCache());
                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "getDrawingCache() == null");
                    }
                    Global.img = bitmap;
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

**Activity B**

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
    {  //receive value and image from C
        if(requestCode==PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(data!=null&&data.hasExtra("text")) {
                c = data.getStringExtra("text");
                txt1.setText(c);
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img);
            }


        }
        else if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        {

        }
    }

  b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // back to A
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                a = "Project";
                text = txt.getText().toString(); // amount
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
                final int k1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("k");
                returnIntent.putExtra("k1", k1);
                returnIntent.putExtra("c",c);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

**Activity A**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  //receive data from B
        int button = data.getIntExtra("k1", 0);

        if (button == 1) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    description=data.getStringExtra("c");
                    if (Global.img != null) {
                        v.setImageBitmap(Global.img);
                    }

                     as=Long.parseLong(result);
                    c.setText("            " + name + "------" + "RM " + result);
                    break;
}

 c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // if c is not null, it can intent to B.Otherwise it is not clickable
  @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
      if ((name != null && name.trim().length() > 0) && (result != null && result.trim().length() > 0)) {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       if (name.equals("Project")) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Project1.class);
       Global.img = null;
       v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,               View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
       View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
       v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
       v.buildDrawingCache(true);
       intent.putExtra("name", name);
       intent.putExtra("result", result);
       intent.putExtra("description", description);
       if (v.getDrawingCache() != null) {
       Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
       if (bitmap == null) {
       Log.e("TAG", "getDrawingCache() == null");
                             }
       Global.img = bitmap;
       startActivity(intent);
                                             }
                                         } 

  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fk + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AlertDialogRadio(a1);


            }
        });

 public void AlertDialogRadio(final int k) {
         final CharSequence[] ClaimsModel = {"B", "Petrol", "Car Maintenance"};

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alt_bld.setTitle("Select a Claims");
        alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(ClaimsModel, -1, new DialogInterface
                .OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), B.class);
                   intent.putExtra("k",k);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }else{...}
}
```

**In A I have textView and button. If textView is clicked, it should display an image on B imageView. If button is clicked, nothing should display on B imageView. Please help,I have no idea...**

Comment: if setting the image to null is all what you need i cant understand why you cant achieve it

Comment: What about setting the View Visibility to INVISIBLE?

Comment: @Shmuel can you explain more on this? Thanks

Comment: view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) will hide the view yet retain the view size for layout purposes. GONE will hide the view and collapse it in the layout.

Comment: @Nanoc sorry for my bad english...I cannot make the image null since I need to access the B two times with different classes

Comment: Still cant find a reason of why you cant set it to null whatever how many times or from where you are getting it. Can you tell me the reason because you think you cant?

Comment: @Shmuel Did you understand my question clearly?  
`view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` really works in my case? Thanks

Comment: @Nanoc ok, i need to pass the value from `C` to `B` then `A.` After that I want to go from `A` to `B` again to edit the value or image. If I set null, the image will be erased and I cannot edit it.

Comment: One thing is to set to null the image of the imageview, and another thing is having a drawable with your image, you can set the imageview content to null while still having the drawable.

Comment: @Nanoc If  set to null, nothing will display on `imageView` when I intent from A to B.

Comment: Are you passing the entire imageView between activities?? to me it looks like you have not read my last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94951/discussion-between-seng-and-nanoc).

Comment: @Nanoc In `A` I have `textView` and `button`. If `textView` is clicked, it should display an image on `B imageView`. If `button` is clicked, nothing should display on `B imageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just simply add  `intent.putExtra("bitmap",true);` in the `c.setOnClickListener`, then add

```
 viewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("bitmap",false))
        {
            viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img);
        }
        else
        {
            viewImage.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
```

in onCreate Activity B